# Prove that the subset $W\subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove
>   $$
> W = \{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}|\exists a\in\mathbb{Z}, a>0\quad s.t\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=f(x+a)\}
> $$
>   is a subspace.
>
> Hint: Show
>   $$
> f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\quad s.t\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=f(x+a)\implies \forall b\in\mathbb{Z}\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=f(x+ab)
> $$

Progress:

I'm having trouble understanding the hint. I tried forming:$$
W'= \{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}|\exists a\in\mathbb{Z}, a>0\quad\forall b\in\mathbb{Z}\quad s.t\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(x)=f(x+ab)\}
$$I'm not sure whether $W=W'$ because of $\forall b\in\mathbb{Z}$. However,  if they are how do you prove so by induction? (This helps with proving $f+g\in W$)

Comment: What is your ambient space to begin with?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed under addition: For $a,b\in{\bf{Z}}$ such that $f(x+a)=f(x)$, $g(x+b)=g(x)$, for all $x\in{\bf{R}}$, then $(f+g)(x+ab)=f(x+ab)+g(x+ab)=f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)$.

Scalar multiplication is easy.

Comment: How do we know that $f(x+ab)+g(x+ab)=f(x)+g(x)$?

Comment: Take for example, $f(x+2)=f(x)$, what do you think $f(x+50)$ is?

Comment: $f(x+52)$ it's all clear now

Comment: No, that is not the point I want to indicate, actually $f(x+50)=f(x)$, the reason is, $f(x+50)=f((x+48)+2)=f(x+48)=f((x+46)+2)=f(x+46)=\cdots=f(x)$.

Comment: Also, how does $f(x+a)=f(x)$, $g(x+b)=g(x)$ contribute to $(f+g)(x+ab)=f(x+ab)+g(x+ab)$?

Comment: That is simply the definition of addition of functions: $A+B$ is defined as $x\rightarrow A(x)+B(x)$, in compact notation, $(A+B)(x)=A(x)+B(x)$.